# Remap copy and paste shortcuts

Tags: 18.04, shortcuts, remapping

In a terminal I have `Alt-C` and `Alt-V` shortcuts to copy/paste.

That's why I want make the same to system wide.

How to remap system wide shortcuts `Ctrl-C` and `Ctrl-V` to `Alt-C` and `Alt-V`?

Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 4):

First, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> are not system wide shortcut keys. They are defined by the application that you use. It is a very widely used convention to use these keys for copy/paste.

As a consequence, if you want to change these bindings, you will need to change them in any application where you want them to change. The [accepted answer in this ask ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/39462/how-do-i-reconfigure-keyboard-shortcuts-for-copy-and-paste?rq=1) may provide some first ideas.

Alternatively, you could redefine the keys of your keyboard, such that <kbd>Alt</kbd> works as the <kbd>Control</kbd> key. That way, your copy shortcuts indeed will be moved to <kbd>Alt</kbd>, but also any other shortcut that programmers defined to be triggered by <kbd>Control</kbd>.